# update() and merge behave differently in case of updating an item in OneToMany collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this a class like bellow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="work")
public class Work {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;


    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true ,mappedBy="work", cascade=CascadeType.ALL , fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<PersonRole> personRoleList;
}
```

As mine is an web application, when i update (comes from client) a  `personRoleList` item and call :

```
session.update(work); //`work` is in detached state
```

It does not update the existing `personRoleList` item it actually add a new one.

Some other people also having the same problem.  REF:
[using-saveorupdate-in-hibernate-creates-new-records-instead-of-updating-existi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857490/using-saveorupdate-in-hibernate-creates-new-records-instead-of-updating-existi)
[jpa-onetomany-not-deleting-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011519/jpa-onetomany-not-deleting-child)

I tried all suggested solution, but none of them work for me.

**But** then i just tried :

```
 session.merge(work);  //replacing session.update(work)
```

And it **works as expected.!!**

This is where I get confused. Because I can't find any explanation for this **difference in behaviors in case of OneToMany relationship** (or may be i missed ). I read some threads to understand the differences between `update()` and `merge()` and gone through the doc. REF:

[what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate)

[differences-among-save-update-saveorupdate-merge-methods-in-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475363/differences-among-save-update-saveorupdate-merge-methods-in-session)

But still it is not clear **What are those behavioral pattern/logic/steps that creating this difference.?**

Comment: when you are working with detached entities, there are chances that you have multiple entities. Now when you want to persist the changes, you need to tell hibernate what changes should go in as there can be multiple dirty versions. So, you have to use merge to make the correct changes.

Comment: Are you asking for the reason that these different methods exist, or are you asking for the reason merge worked and update didn't?

Comment: I am asking for the reason merge worked and update didn't? @Tyler

Answer (score 2):

Merge attempts to associate a currently transient object with a persistent object currently under management by the session by 'merging' them into one entity. Its intended use is when you have a detached object *and* an attached object and wish to resolve them.

In a `merge()`, Hibernate will read the entity from the database if there isn't already a managed instance in the session. In your example, this will result in Hibernate eagerly loading the collection (due to `fetch=FetchType.EAGER`). Then when your session ends, Hibernate will check for changes in the collection (due to `cascade=CascadeType.ALL`) and will perform the appropriate UPDATE in the database.

This differs from the `update()` scenario because in an update Hibernate always (by default) assumes the object is dirty and schedules an UPDATE. This update is likely what's causing creation of a new element in your collection - Hibernate hasn't looked in the database to bring the collection into session before issuing the UPDATE.

I'd bet you can get the desired behavior of `update()` by setting

`select-before-update="true"`

in your class mapping or by using the `lock` method to re-attach your object to the session before making changes.

From Chapter 9 of *[Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://jpwh.org/)*

*It doesn’t matter if the item object is modified before or after it’s passed to 
update(). The important thing here is that the call to update() is reattaching  the detached instance to the new Session (and persistence context). Hibernate
always treats the object as dirty and schedules an SQL UPDATE, which will be executed during flush. You can see the same unit of work in figure 9.8.
 You may be surprised and probably hoped that Hibernate could know that you
modified the detached item’s description (or that Hibernate should know you did
not modify anything). However, the new Session and its fresh persistence context
don’t have this information. Neither does the detached object contain some internal list of all the modifications you’ve made.
UDPATE in the database is needed. One way to avoid this UDPATE statement is to
configure the class mapping of Item with the select-before-update="true"
attribute. Hibernate then determines whether the object is dirty by executing a
SELECT statement and comparing the object’s current state to the current data-
base state.*